# FormulaArray with Lastrow not working

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get the count of the data from 1 number to before next 1 in cell D using formula but which i am able to get it using a formula

```
Index   Level   Header  Test
3        3       ADD    1
4        4       AAC    
5        5       AAG    
6        3       ASC    1
7        4       AIA    
9        4       ABB    1
10       5       APP    
12       5       BBS    1
13       6       SST    
3        3       AIUH   1
4        4       AAC    
5        5       AAG    
6        3      The ASC 1
7        4      AIA 
9        4      ABB Inc 1
10       5      APP 
12       5      BBS     1
13       6      SST 
3        3      AIUH    1
4        4      AAC 
5        5      AAG 
6        3      ASC     1
7        4      AIA 
9        4      ABB     1
10       5      APP 
12       5      BBS     1
13       6      SST
```

Cell G2 with Value 1 for reference

```
"=SMALL(IF($D$2:$D$100=$H$2,ROW($D$2:$D$100)),ROW(D1)+1)-SMALL(IF($D$2:$D$100=$H$2,ROW($D$2:$D$100)),ROW(D1))"
```

But i am not able use this in vba using last row & fillarray or filldown also

would be helpful if any of the experts take a moment and help me with this

```
Sub tes()
Dim LR As Long
LR = Cells(rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("sheet3").Activate
With Sheets("sheet3")
.Range("C1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 1).Value = 1
.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="1"
.Range("C1").Select
.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Copy
.Range("L1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll

If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = True Then ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
.Range("H1") = "Value"
.Range("H2") = 1
.Range("M1") = "Count"

'Which is working cell wise
.Range("M2").FormulaArray = "=SMALL(IF($D$2:$D$100=$H$2,ROW($D$2:$D$100)),ROW(D1)+1)-SMALL(IF($D$2:$D$100=$H$2,ROW($D$2:$D$100)),ROW(D1))"


'Trying to fill down using filldown not working
.Range("L1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1).Select
.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
.Selection.FillDown

'Trying to use lastrow in column with Fillarray which is also not working
.Range("M2:M" & LR).FormulaArray = "=SMALL(IF($D$2:$D$100=$G$2,ROW($D$2:$D$100)),ROW(D1)+1)-SMALL(IF($D$2:$D$100=$G$2,ROW($D$2:$D$100)),ROW(D1))"


End With

End Sub
```

I even tried not to use Activate or select but i am not sure how to go without these here.

Thanks a lot experts and have a great weekend!!

I have shared the link also for reference [enter link description here](http://enter%20link%20description%20here)

Comment: When using formulaarray references must be in r1c1 format.

Comment: Thank you @scott craner will try r1c1 format n get back Good day !!

Comment: @ScottCraner expert, i tried with this but i am getting same result in all the cells of the column with first result of 3 for all cells in the column - Here is the formula which i have used would be helpful if you can correct me .Range("N2:N" & LR).FormulaArray = "=SMALL(IF(R2C4:R100C4=R2C8,ROW(R2C2:R100C4)),ROW(R1C4)+1)-SMALL(IF(R2C4:R100C4=R2C8,ROW(R2C4:R100C4)),ROW(R1C4))"
 Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the formula into the first cell using the [Range.FormulaArray property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837104.aspx) then finish the rest of the range with the [Range.FillDown method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838404.aspx).

```
With Worksheets("Sheet3")
    .Range("M2").FormulaArray = _
      "=SMALL(IF($D$2:$D$100=$H$2,ROW($B$2:$D$100)),ROW(1:1)+1)-SMALL(IF($D$2:$D$100=$H$2,ROW($D$2:$D$100)),ROW(1:1))"
    .Range("M2:M" & lr).FillDown
    .Range("N2").FormulaArray = _
      "=SMALL(IF(R2C4:R100C4=R2C8,ROW(R2C2:R100C4)),ROW(R[-1])+1)-SMALL(IF(R2C4:R100C4=R2C8,ROW(R2C4:R100C4)),ROW(R[-1]))"
    .Range("N2:N" & lr).FillDown        
End With
```

Both **xlA1** and **xlR1C1** formula syntax will work with the .FormulaArray property but you need to start with a single cell.

Comment: Thank you Expert @Jeeped :) both are working perfectly and i got to know that i should be using cell reference B to D in row formula because of which it thrown error and if you find time please tell me at the end Row(D1) replaced with Row(1:1) too and what this will used for??? thanks again

Comment: That part of the formula is simply going to be **1** in the first place you use it then **2, 3, 4** etc as you fill it down. It doesn't matter if you use `ROW(D1)` or `ROW(1:1)` but `ROW($D$1)` will not work because it stays **1**, not **2, 3, 4** etc as you fill it down.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation got its just cell reference first one and second one row reference... thanks again Expert @ Jeeped :)